# how to see wall clock time in visual studio profiler

Tags: visual-studio-2015

The Visual Studio Profiler can show me the methods where a high amount of CPU time is spent, but suppose there is some database (or other I/O) operation that is the bottleneck.  I would like to see what method is taking the longest amount of wall clock time.  How can I see that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently CPU Usage Tool in Visual Studio does not provide elapsed time information. To get elapsed time you can use Performance Wizard: invoke Debug > Start Diagnostic Tools Without Debugging > Performance Wizard > Start and choose Instrumentation as a profiling method. You will get Elapsed Exclusive Time and Elapsed Inclusive Time data in profiler views.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe .Net Async checkbox in profile tool can help